# how to create a cover flow menu like ipod app when turn in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, coverflow

As per title, how to create such cover flow menu? Have any reference code or tutorial talk about this?

Answer (score 1):

When you install Xcode, look in

> /Developer/Examples/Quartz/Core
>   Animation/CoverFlow

to find an example coverflow app. I hope this helps you.

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore and I can't seem to find it on Apple's website. Do you know where it is hiding these days?

Comment: No idea - try Google.  It's where I found the information in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Plausible Labs has a licensable implementation of a CoverFlow-like UI [here](http://www.plausiblelabs.com/code/pljukebox/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m

This is open source project base on opengles. hope this can help